# Database creation not working android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am a windows phone developer and new to android database,
I am unable to create a local db in android
I am unable to understand where i am doing wrong

I will be storing some data in my DB and later would fetch it to populate my listview.

Currently i am unable to create a sample database, below is my code

```
public final class DbContract {

public DbContract() {
}

private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
private static DatabaseHelper dbHandler;
Context context;

public DatabaseHelper database;

/* Inner classes that defines the all table contents */

/**
 * Hospital database structure, query
 * */

public static abstract class Hospital implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "emergency_hospital";
    public static final String HOSPITAL_NAME = "name";
    public static final String HOSPITAL_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String HOSPITAL_CONTACT_NUMBER = "number";

}

private static final String SQL_CREATE_EMERGENCY_HOSPITAL = "CREATE TABLE "
        + Hospital.TABLE_NAME + " (" + Hospital._ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Hospital.HOSPITAL_NAME + TEXT_TYPE
        + COMMA_SEP + Hospital.HOSPITAL_ADDRESS + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP
        + Hospital.HOSPITAL_CONTACT_NUMBER + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP + " );";

private static final String SQL_DELETE_EMERGENCY_HOSPITAL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
        + Hospital.TABLE_NAME;

/**
 * Handles database versions, create and populate tables in database
 **/

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sample.db";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_EMERGENCY_HOSPITAL);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade
        // policy is
        // to simply to discard the whole database and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_EMERGENCY_HOSPITAL);
        onCreate(db);
    }


}

public static DatabaseHelper getDbHandler() {
    return dbHandler;
}

public void HospitalData() {
    // Gets the data repository in write mode
    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

    // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Hospital.HOSPITAL_NAME, "Bellevue Hospital Centre");
    values.put(Hospital.HOSPITAL_ADDRESS, "Manhattan");
    values.put(Hospital.HOSPITAL_CONTACT_NUMBER, "4356754");

    // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
    long newRowId;

    newRowId = db.insert(Hospital.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}

}
```

**In my main activity it is**

```
private static DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
dbHelper = DbContract.getDbHandler();
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

**My manifest says**

```
<provider
        android:name=".database.DbContract"
        android:authorities="com.demo" >
    </provider>
```

**Is this the right way to initialize db creation ?**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(2069): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.demo.database.DbContract: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.demo.database.DbContract cannot be cast to android.content.ContentProvider

 E/AndroidRuntime(2069):    at           com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
  E/AndroidRuntime(2069): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:        com.demo.database.DbContract cannot be cast to android.content.ContentProvider
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: actually you wrote wrong query... first you have to correct it...

Comment: I have added the logs can you please check

Answer (score 1):

Your mainfest file has provider tag with name as ".database.DbContract". This is the root cause of exception you are getting.
Provider tag is used for declaring content provider and the name tag can be the package name of the content provider but in your case its not the name of any content provider sub class. Hence getting class cast exception.
Please read the basics of content provicer:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html

Hope it help you!!!